# Regex pro­blem with finding first space

Tags: notepad++

I have such lines:

```
url.ru/?kluch word word word
url.ru/?2kluch word
url.ru/?2kluch word word
url.ru/?2kluch_word word-word
```

I need to put | between url and first space.

Try this:

**Find**: ^(.+)\s(.+)

**Replace with:** $1|$2

But it doesn't work how i need.

Comment: @Noel I think it's pretty clear, sample input `url.ru/?kluch word word word` , output `url.ru/?kluch|word word word`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is working for me:
Find `^([^\s]+)\s`
Replace `$1|`